# Python dynamic looping function error (module not callable)

Tags: python, function, api, loops, date

I have a long function pulling data out of an API (not included here). I use the following call to get the output data frame.

```
get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (startdate, enddate, lat, long, fields = None)
```

Unfortunately I cannot get more than one year's of data from the API...

Per the recommendation of a stack overflow member, I am using the following wrapper_function to loop through a longer range of dates.

```
def my_wrapper_func(startdate, enddate):
    middle_years = range(startdate.year+1, enddate.year)
    _all = []
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
    for year in middle_years:
        _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(year, 1, 1), datetime(year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
    return _all

my_wrapper_func(datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2016,11,8))
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`datetime` is the name of the module. You need to do `datetime.datetime()` to get the data type.

Or you can do

```
from datetime import datetime  # 'from datetime import *' if you're feeling adventurous
my_wrapper_func(datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2016,11,8))
```